# How to use an npm package in an existing AngularJS project?

Tags: angularjs, npm

Trying to use screenshot-desktop NPM package in an existing AngularJS application

Answer (score 0):

Download and install nodeJs from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ then goto terminal(nix) or command prompt(Win) then go to you angular project directory which you have just created using Intellij wizard where your package.json file existing.. run command 'npm install'

Comment: I have done all that and installed the required package. But how do I use that package in project?